# how to test angular js in eclipse for maven project?

Tags: angularjs

In my project there is *RESTful web services* and I am using **angularjs** for front-end. But I am not able to figure out how to test angularjs in eclipse environment.

Is there any way to achieve it?

I have already install karma.

Answer (score 1):

My sugestion would be to use Jasmine tests.

http://jasmine.github.io/

As you already installed karma, you can automize a grunt taskt "test", for instance, to write all the tests.

This approach is independent from eclipse, you can use it with a terminal.